# Alternate proof that $\exists\ x \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $ \gcd (a+bx,c) = 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I came across this question in the book *An Excursion in Mathematics:*

> Let $a,b,c \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $\gcd(a,b) =1, c>0$. Prove that $\exists\ x \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $ \gcd (a+bx,c) = 1$.

There is one proof that is easy enough: By Dirichlet's Theorem, there are infinitely many primes of the form $a+bx$ where $a,b$ are relatively prime, so we merely take the first prime of the form $a+bx>c$.

On the other hand, however, the book is a fairly elementary textbook on high-school math contests and Dirichlet's theorem is not mentioned. I am having difficulty coming up with another proof for this. I have tried to *construct* an $x$ such that $a+bx$ is relatively prime to $c$, but to no avail.

How would I proceed towards the proof?

Comment: If 1)  $\text{gcd}(a,c)≠1$, and also as $\text{gcd}(b,a)=1$ take any $x$ such that $\text{gcd}(x,a,c)=1$.If 2) $\text{gcd}(a,c)=1$ take $x=c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a prime factor $p$ of $c$. Then if $p\mid b$, $p\nmid a$
and all $x$ satisfy $a+bx\not\equiv0\pmod p$. If $p\nmid b$ the solutions
to $a+bx\equiv1\pmod p$ form a conguruence class modulo $p$.

All one needs is to choose $x$ so that $a+bx\equiv1\pmod p$ for all primes
$p\mid c$, $p\nmid b$. Now use Chinese Remainder Theorem.